# searching for a verbatim package for paragraphs that use reserved characters

Tags: pdftex, verbatim

I'm looking for a LaTeX package that enables an environment sort of like "verbatim" in that it prints each and every unicode character exactly as typed, but... 
1> does NOT replicate linebreaks
2> uses the \normalfont
3> justifies, hyphenates and prints the text as LaTeX would normally

I would use it to typeset paragraphs of text from a txt file. (I want it typeset, I don't want it to look like it was printed from notepad or a typewriter)

The text is full of @ # $ % characters that otherwise require special attention to print out, so I figure a lot of folks run into this routinely.  Is there a package to help?

Comment: Please provide specific examples of entire paragraphs.

Comment: Have you looked at the `fancyvrb` package? There are lots of options available there that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need commands in the text to typeset, a simplified version of jfbu's macros is available. It's also easy to turn the environment into an “input” type macro.

As jfbu's macros, this code relies on using T1 encoded fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\textverbatim{%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode` =10
  \text@verbatim
}
\edef\text@verb@end{%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\string\x 
  end\string{textverbatim\string}%
}
\begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\long\def\text@verbatim##1}
\expandafter\x\text@verb@end{%
  \ignorespaces#1\endgroup\ignorespaces
}

\newcommand{\textverbatiminput}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode` =10
  \input{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}

\begin{textverbatim}
I'm looking for a LaTeX package that enables an environment
sort of like "verbatim" in that it prints each and every 
unicode character exactly as typed, but... 1> does NOT 
replicate linebreaks 2> uses the \normalfont 3> justifies, 
hyphenates and prints the text as LaTeX would normally

I would use it to typeset paragraphs of text from a txt file. 
(I want it typeset, I don't want it to look like it was 
printed from notepad or a typewriter)

The text is full of @ # $ % characters that otherwise require 
special attention to print out, so I figure a lot of folks run 
into this routinely. Is there a package to help?

Here are most characters (originally copied from the pdf 

http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf

\also\some\backslash#@&%%%

./myverbatim.tex:209: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+126)

Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

Test of Unicode in verbatim:
ĀāĂăĄą ĆćĈĉĊċČč ĎďĐđ ĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚě ĜĝĞğĠġĢģ Ĥĥ
ĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİı Ĵĵ Ķķ ĹĺĻļĽľL·l·Łł ŃńŅņŇň Ŋŋ ŌōŎŏŐőŒœ
ŔŕŖŗŘř ŚśŜŝŞşŠš ŢţŤť ŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲų Ŵŵ ŶŷŸ ŹźŻżŽž
\end{textverbatim}
Back to \textbf{normal}: $E=mc^2$.

\textverbatiminput{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend accepting that answer rather than mine; for some reason I wanted to try out something different, which would work if the spaces were not normal, but with normal spaces, the approach in my answer has the defect explained in my comments. The approach here is better.

Comment: that's honorable! your answer offered a lot of insights, so it comes in handy

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a package for this.

The update at bottom of answer is for slightly more complicated coding which requires `\end{myverbatim}` and not only `\end{myver` to decide that the end of the environment has been hit.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\{ 12 \catcode`\( 1
    \def\myverbatim@endtag (end{myver}
\catcode`\{ 1 \catcode`\( 12

\def\myverbatim@backslash #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9%
{%
    \def\myverbatim@temp{#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9}%
    \ifx\myverbatim@temp\myverbatim@endtag
          \expandafter\myverbatim@stop
    \else \@backslashchar\expandafter\myverbatim@temp
    \fi
}

\def\myverbatim@stop batim#1{\end{myverbatim}}

\begingroup
    \lccode`\~ 92
    \lowercase{%
\gdef\myverbatim@makeintelligentbackslash 
   {\catcode92 \active \let~\myverbatim@backslash}%
              }
\endgroup   
\newenvironment{myverbatim}{\let\do\@makeother \dospecials
   \catcode32 10 % normal spaces
   \myverbatim@makeintelligentbackslash % exit properly
   }{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myverbatim}
I'm looking for a LaTeX package that enables an environment sort of like "verbatim" in that it prints each and every unicode character exactly as typed, but... 1> does NOT replicate linebreaks 2> uses the \normalfont 3> justifies, hyphenates and prints the text as LaTeX would normally

I would use it to typeset paragraphs of text from a txt file. (I want it typeset, I don't want it to look like it was printed from notepad or a typewriter)

The text is full of @ # $ % characters that otherwise require special attention to print out, so I figure a lot of folks run into this routinely. Is there a package to help?

Here are most characters (originally copied from the pdf 

http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf

directly from firefox pdf viewer to an emacs buffer) in Unicode Latin
Extended-A, five of them were "not set up for use with LaTeX." and thus I suppressed them.

(don't worry about line numbers)

./myverbatim.tex:209: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+126)

./myverbatim.tex:210: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+127)

./myverbatim.tex:227: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+138)

./myverbatim.tex:244: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+2BC)

./myverbatim.tex:273: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+166)

./myverbatim.tex:274: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+167)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

...

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

Test of Unicode in verbatim: Ā
ā
Ă
ă
Ą
ą
Ć
ć
Ĉ
ĉ
Ċ
ċ
Č
č
Ď
ď
Đ
đ
Ē
ē
Ĕ
ĕ
Ė
ė
Ę
ę
Ě
ě
Ĝ
ĝ
Ğ
ğ
Ġ
ġ
Ģ
ģ
Ĥ
ĥ
Ĩ
ĩ
Ī
ī
Ĭ
ĭ
Į
į
İ
ı
IJ
ij
Ĵ
ĵ
Ķ
ķ
Ĺ
ĺ
Ļ
ļ
Ľ
ľ
L·
l·
Ł
ł
Ń
ń
Ņ
ņ
Ň
ň
Ŋ
ŋ
Ō
ō
Ŏ
ŏ
Ő
ő
Œ
œ
Ŕ
ŕ
Ŗ
ŗ
Ř
ř
Ś
ś
Ŝ
ŝ
Ş
ş
Š
š
Ţ
ţ
Ť
ť
Ũ
ũ
Ū
ū
Ŭ
ŭ
Ů
ů
Ű
ű
Ų
ų
Ŵ
ŵ
Ŷ
ŷ
Ÿ
Ź
ź
Ż
ż
Ž
ž
s
\end{myverbatim}%$ to stop emacs fontification due to $ and also test if % ok $

Back to \textbf{normal}: $E=mc^2$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

---

Here is the safer code which requires the full `\end{myverbatim}` as end tag.

The `\end{myverbatim}` does not create a paragraph, it can be continued
on the very same line with some normal stuff. Similarly the
`\begin{myverbatim}` does not start a paragraph and does not even insert
a space if used as `\begin{myverbatim}STUFF`. Thus this environment `myverbatim` can be used also for "short verbatim" inside an otherwise normal paragraph.

```
\makeatletter
\catcode`\{ 12 \catcode`\( 1
    \def\myverbatim@endtagA (end{myver}
\catcode`\{ 1 \catcode`\( 12
\catcode`\} 12 \catcode`\) 2
    \def\myverbatim@endtagB {batim})
\catcode`\} 2 \catcode`\) 12

\def\myverbatim@backslash #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9%
{%
    \def\myverbatim@tempA{#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9}%
    \ifx\myverbatim@tempA\myverbatim@endtagA
          \expandafter\myverbatim@makesure
    \else \@backslashchar\expandafter\myverbatim@tempA
    \fi
}

\def\myverbatim@makesure #1#2#3#4#5#6%
{%
    \def\myverbatim@tempB{#1#2#3#4#5#6}%
    \ifx\myverbatim@tempB\myverbatim@endtagB
          \expandafter\myverbatim@stop
    \fi 
    \@backslashchar\expandafter\myverbatim@tempA\myverbatim@tempB
}

\def\myverbatim@stop\@backslashchar
    \expandafter\myverbatim@tempA\myverbatim@tempB{\end{myverbatim}}

\begingroup
    \lccode`\~ 92
    \lowercase{%
\gdef\myverbatim@makeintelligentbackslash 
   {\catcode92 \active \let~\myverbatim@backslash}%
              }
\endgroup   
\newenvironment{myverbatim}{\let\do\@makeother \dospecials
   \catcode32 10 % normal spaces
   \myverbatim@makeintelligentbackslash % exit properly
   }{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I think that coding should be put into a package and made available on CTAN because it's potentially useful for so many people.  Packages aren't required by programmers who can type up code all day long, but they certainly are convenient for non programmers who leisurely use LaTeX.  As for me, I'm going to create my own personal package of that. nice work

Comment: excellent, this is what I really need: "The \end{myverbatim} does not create a paragraph, it can be continued on the very same line with normal stuff. "

Comment: @user12711 I have added to my answer the more robust version which requires  `\end{myverbatim}` and not only `\end{myver` as closing tag.

Comment: @user12711 my approach is not perfect. In certain circumstances it can gobble spaces (when it handles control sequences to check if it is `\end{myverbatim}`.) I have for personal uses other types of "free-flowing" verbatims. The approach here can be modified to not have this problem, but perhaps it is not worth it to make the extra effort if you only use it with text having some special characters but no backslash.

Comment: @user12711 I feel a bit guilty about my original but not perfect approach; with a `\verb|...|` type of syntax it is much easier; or it is also possible (and arguably better) to mimic more of standard verbatim, but in a free-flowing way, not using typewriter font also. But I wanted to try something new. It works fine, except that encountered control sequences `\foo bar1 bar2` will lose the spaces between `\foo` and `bar1` and between  `bar1` and `bar2`.

Comment: @user12711 egreg has provided the simpler coding, which uses a delimited macro as in standard approach to verbatim environment. I recommend you move the tick to his answer !