# In LuaTeX, how can I escape text that will be inserted in LaTeX?

Tags: luatex

I wrote a Lua function that dumps data from a TXT file in my LaTeX document. The problem I have right now is that the data the TXT file is treated as LaTeX code so I need to escape special characters with backslashes and so on. Is there a way to treat the data from the TXT file as "plain text" without any LaTeX formatting?

My hunch is that either:

- There is a LaTeX macro for this. kindof like `verbatim`, but without displaying my text in typewriter font.
- There is ready-made LuaTeX macro or function for this. Basically the opposite of `\luaescapestring`
- I'll have to write down a special-character-escaping function by hand.

---

Source for `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile("test.lua")}
\begin{document}

\directlua{test("test.txt")}

\end{document}
```

Source for `test.lua`:

```
function test(filename)
  local file = io.open(filename)
  local s = file:read("*a")
  tex.print(s)
  file:close()
end
```

My current `test.txt`, which uses LaTeX formatting:

```
Hello \$\#\%!
```

My desired `test.txt` would be plain text and possibly contain any special characters:

```
Hello $#%!
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301881/searching-for-a-verbatim-package-for-paragraphs-that-use-reserved-characters

Comment: Use `tex.print(-2, s)`. That should be it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `tex.print(-2,s)` to get the desired output.

Background: the function `tex.print()` accepts different numbers of parameters. In the simplest variant, it accepts the string that should be output. It also accepts a "catcode table" as the first argument (a number). There are predefined catcode tables, and -2 is a catcode table where all special characters are not special anymore. Therefore `tex.print(-2,"#")` does not insert a "# with catcode 6" but "# with catcode 12". As you all know, 12 is the catcode for "other characters" which are harmles.